# What file asked to include file x?

Tags: php

Is it possible to see what page made the include inside the included file?

I need to be able to see what page included a file to make decisions based on who the caller is.

Comment: *"I need to be able to see what page included a file to make decisions based on who the caller is."* -- this is wrong. Put the code in the included files in functions and let the includer control what functions it calls and with what arguments. Otherwise you'll have to change the included file every time you include it into a new file, move/rename one of the includers etc.

Comment: `debug_backtrace`